# React hook component: isLoading in state and data in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I use React with the entire redux and redux saga ecosystem. I want to make a component with useState and useEffect where isLoading will be in state.

At this point, it looks like this, but I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing:

// Redux Initial State:

```
export const initialState = {
  amountMoney: '',
  currencyName: '',
  accountBalanceHistory: [],
};
```

// Data after redux success:

```
amountMoney: '231.0';
currencyName: 'name';
accountBalanceHistory: [2,3,4];
```

// Example Component:

```
export default function ExampleComponent() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { amountMoney, accountBalanceHistory, currencyName } = useSelector(
    stateSelector,
  );

  const getAmountMoney = () => dispatch(getAmountMoneyAction()); //this changes amountMoney and CurrencyName
  const getAccountBalanceHistory = () =>
    dispatch(getAccountBalanceHistoryAction()); //this changes accountBalanceHistory

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!accountBalanceHistory.length) {
      getAccountBalanceHistory();
    }

    if (!amountMoney || !currencyName) {
      getAmountMoney();
    }

    if (amountMoney && currencyName && accountBalanceHistory.length) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [amountMoney && currencyName && accountBalanceHistory]);

  return (...)
}
```

It works, but I think it is not written correctly. The problem is that accountBalanceHistory is an array. How to write it more correctly?

Comment: It's unclear what is the problem... Why an array is a problem?...

Comment: @DennisVash it's about infinite component rendering (dispatch action) etc. This is how it works, as I wrote it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You should consider having the loading state in redux since that makes your code more deteminant